# Flutter App Host Errors "Failed host lookup: '$host'"

Tags: flutter, proxy, localhost, port, host

When i run my flutter app in the debug  console within visual studio code. I get the following messages

```
    "Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
    √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
    Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:61843/B4tZiYo4ANE=/ws
    I/madra.brew_cre(10170): Background concurrent copying GC freed 28317(6MB) 
    AllocSpace 
    objects, 5(96KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1944KB/3MB, paused 1.286ms total 114.385ms
    D/eglCodecCommon(10170): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
    D/EGL_emulation(10170): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe9586440: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd0ce8ff0)"
```

Then i get an error in the socket_patch.dart file

```
    "Failed host lookup: '$host'"
```

But i notice that when i run the same program from terminal or Android studio. it builds successfully, it also builds fine when i restrict it to an observation port at runtime. The only difference when i run on terminal vs debug console is that it runs it on a different port automatically when i run it from Terminal.

```
"Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
 Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              9.7s
 √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
 Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...                     217ms
 A Dart VM Service on AOSP on IA Emulator is available at: 
 http://127.0.0.1:62597/G44aJh3yYYE=/
 The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on AOSP on IA Emulator is available at: 
 http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:62597/G44aJh3yYYE=/
 D/eglCodecCommon(10659): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
 D/EGL_emulation(10659): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd67fd2e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7b2ac70)"
```

I thought i might have proxy settings or http/https env variables set up that causes this behavior but my system is set to automatically detect proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did it work returned with previous dart stable version, i hope work for you.

```
flutter doctor -v
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: I just wanted to say that this solution worked for me. I had given up and started building in Android studio. But this actually fixed the issue

Comment: Although the issue doesn't crash my app or anything, it is annoying every time I refresh the app in development because the debugger picks it up. Unfortunately, 'flutter doctor -v' shows that everything is perfect, and even after switching to stable and running 'flutter upgrade', the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file